# Invalid operation in OpenGL drawing procedure. What causes it?

Tags: opengl, rendering

I wrote this code,

```
void _3DGraphic::Render(){
glBindVertexArray(uiVAO[0]);
int HModelView = glGetUniformLocation(m_pShaderProgram->GetProgramID(), "gModelView");
int HProjection = glGetUniformLocation(m_pShaderProgram->GetProgramID(), "gProjection");
glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, 1.0f, 0.001f, 1000.0f);
glUniformMatrix2fv(HProjection, 1, GL_FALSE, &projection[0][0]);

glm::mat4 mModelView = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0, 30,-10.0f ), glm::vec3(0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));


mModelView = glm::rotate(0.1f, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));

glUniformMatrix4fv(HModelView, 1, GL_FALSE, &mModelView[0][0]);


glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12);
```

}

And got an "Invalid Operation" error from OGL when running it. What causes it?

**edit:**
The error seems to be given on each of these open gl calls. I checked that before the "invalid operation" error, the gl error returns a few "invalid enumerant"errors as well.

Comment: intersperse glGetError() called between the other lg calls, look where it returns something non-zero

Comment: As Mr Ratchet Freak said, use glGetError or step through the code in your debugger to pinpoint the offending code.

Comment: The `glUniformMatrix2fv()` call for the projection matrix certainly looks wrong. That should be `glUniformMatrix4fv()`. But I don't think that would give an invalid operation. It will result in bad rendering, or potentially a crash.